How to load table from SQLLite db file located in HDFS from PySpark?
I am trying to load table from an SQLLite .db file stored at in HDFS  in PySpark but i keep getting this error  even though the file exists in the correct hdfs directory :
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'hdfs://localhost:9000//user/hadoop/project/dataset/a97be29a-1c3f-4fe9-afce-d4da4a8667ab': '/home/hadoop/coding/hdfs:' does not exist
here's my code :
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
           .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc:3.45.3.0')\
           .getOrCreate()


 

# Define JDBC URL
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlite:/home/hadoop/data/a97be29a-1c3f-4fe9-afce-d4da4a8667ab"


hdfs_base_url = "hdfs://localhost:9000"
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + hdfs_base_url + "/user/hadoop/project/dataset/a97be29a-1c3f-4fe9-afce-d4da4a8667ab"

# Load data from SQLite database into Spark DataFrame
table_name = "RealTimeData"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable=table_name,
                 url=jdbc_url)\
        .option("customSchema", "date STRING")\
        .load()

df.show(5)

i tried running the code on a local db file and it worked , the problem is in the jdbc_url , is there any way to solve it ?

The hdfs:// URL isn't allowed in sqlite JDBC strings. Sqlite files can only be locally stored

is there an alternative solution to deal with sqlite files in hadoop storage and extract them efficiently to use them in spark ?

If possible, I'd suggest coverting the sqlite files to parquet before uploading. Otherwise, I don't think they can be read from there directly using any tool
